# show that a matrix is similar to a block matrix using minimal polynomial

Tags: minimal-polynomials, block-matrices, primary-decomposition

$$\begin{pmatrix}1&0&-4&4\\ \:\:\:\:0&2&0&0\\ \:\:\:\:0&1&1&0\\ \:\:\:\:0&1&0&1\end{pmatrix}$$

I need to find a matrix $P$ where $PAP^{-1}=D$ where $D=\begin{pmatrix}X&0\\ 0&Y\end{pmatrix}$ is a block matrix of blocks $X,Y$ are blocks.

My solution:

I found the minimal polynomial which is $m\left(x\right)=\left(x-1\right)^2\left(x-2\right)$
and as I know, the matrix $A$ in base of the eugenvectors should give me the D I want and then the $P$  is the matrix of the eugenvectors, but I didn't got this result:

$$\begin{pmatrix}1&0&0&0\\ 0&-1&1&0\\ 0&-1&0&1\\ 0&1&0&0\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}1&0&-4&4\\ 0&2&0&0\\ 0&1&1&0\\ 0&1&0&1\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}1&0&0&0\\ 0&0&0&1\\ 0&1&0&1\\ 0&0&1&1\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}1&-4&4&0\\ 0&1&0&0\\ 0&0&1&0\\ 0&0&0&2\end{pmatrix}$$

in this case $$P=\begin{pmatrix}1&0&0&0\\ 0&0&0&1\\ 0&1&0&1\\ 0&0&1&1\end{pmatrix}$$

because: $$Ker\left(A-2I\right)=sp\left\{\left(0,1,1,1\right)\right\}$$

and $$Ker\left(\left(A-I\right)^2\right)=sp\left\{\left(1,0,0,0\right),\:\left(0,0,1,0\right),\:0,0,0,1\right\}$$

but $D$ isn't as needed, and I don't see what did I wrong in this solution path.

Comment: Why did you stick the eigenvector for $2$ in the middle of the generalized eigenvectors for the other eigenvalue? You have to keep related generalized eigenvectors together if you want to end up with tidy Jordan blocks.

Comment: just tried different order, but still it doesn't end up with Jordan blocks and as much as I can tell, I don't see any calculation error, checked it with calculator.